Regex: How to include a character in previous group when matched in next group
I have the following regex:
(.+)([) ._-]+[a-z])()(\.[^.]+)$

I want it to match a filename that ends (before the extension) with one of )   . _ - followed by a letter.
Using this example (using case insensitive matching)
The.Chronicles-A.mp4

Matches with
Group 1 The.Chronicles
Group 2 -A

which is what I want.
But if I have (where the single character before the letter is ))
The.Chronicles.(2001)A.mp4

I get
Group 1 The.Chronicles.(2001
Group 2 )A

Is there any way to modify the regex so in the second example group 1 is The.Chronicles.(2001) - with the ) that matches in the second group included in the first?? (but any other of the possible letters don't appear in the first group. I don't care whether they are in the second group or not)

Something like ^(.+)((?:[._-]|(?<=\)))[^.]*)(\.[^.]+)$?

Thank you. I've tweaked a little and I think ^(.+)((?:[ ._-]|(?<=\)))[a-z])()(\.[^.]+)$ does it.

What is () in the middle of the regexp for?

I don't get any match at all with your original regexp. https://regex101.com/r/L6Td7k/1  -- never mind, I needed to add the i flag.

What should be in group 2 in your second example? The regexp doesn't allow it to be empty.

Thanks. The () just makes the third group empty so the extension is in the 4th (needed for the code). I don't mind what is in the 2nd group - it could be )A or just A - it is the movie name (+/- year) that I want in the first to be constant.

@Andy, do not forget to upvоtе answers that you find helpful.

You can use an alternation to either match a space, ., _ or -, OR a location right after ):
^(.+)((?:[ ._-]|(?<=\)))[a-z])()(\.[^.]+)$
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

See the regex demo. Mind the i flag used, so in the code, you need to use a case ignore flag or an option, too.
Details:

^ - start of string
(.+) - Group 1: one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
((?:[ ._-]|(?<=\)))[a-z]) - Group 2: either a space, ., _ or -, or  a location right after a ), and then an ASCII letter
() - an empty Group 3 (needed for your code, if code can be adjusted, this is not necessary)
(\.[^.]+) - Group 4: . and then one or more chars other than a .
$ - end of string.

